# this for loop using arrays seems do not work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, overwrite, async.js

I was experimenting with loops, but it seems that I miss a piece here:
In this piece of code I use the same array[] twice.

I copy whole array[] into the first position of an array[[]]

then I overwrite the array[]

and copy the whole array[] with new values in to the second position of array[[]]

BUT

for some reason the first position is changed too??????

this is what I expected: `65,44,12,4,23,42`

this is what I got:      `4,23,42,4,23,42`

I think it may be due to async features of JS but if you have a better explanation and a solution...

Thx a lot

```
var numbers = [65, 44, 12, 4, 23, 42];

function pippo() {

  var k = 3;
  var colonne = [];
  var riga = [
    []
  ];

  for (j = 1; j < k + 1; j++) {
    y = 0 * k + j - 1;
    colonne[j - 1] = numbers[y];
  }

  riga[0] = colonne;

  for (j = 1; j < k + 1; j++) {
    y = 1 * k + j - 1;
    colonne[j - 1] = numbers[y];
  }

  riga[1] = colonne;

  demo.innerHTML = riga[0].concat(riga[1]);
}
```

------------------- this the full code. The idea is to experiment with for to chunk the nmbers array.

here the whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="pippo()">Try it</button>

<p>Updated array: <span id="demo"></span></p>


<script>
var numbers = [65, 44, 12, 4, 23 , 42];

function pippo() {

var k = 3;
var colonne = [];
var riga = [[]];


for (j=1;j<k+1;j++ ){
        y = 0*k+j-1;
        colonne[j-1] = numbers[y];
}

riga[0] = colonne;

for (j=1;j<k+1;j++ ){
        y = 1*k+j-1;
        colonne[j-1] = numbers[y];
}

riga[1] = colonne;

demo.innerHTML = riga[0].concat(riga[1]);   

}


</script>

</body>
</html>

//-------------------the original outer loop:

for (w = 0 ;w < (numbers.length)/k ;w++) {

for (j=1;j<k+1;j++ ){
        y = w*k+j-1;
        colonne[j-1] = numbers[y];
}

riga[w] = colonne;

}
```

Comment: First thansk a lot for the answers got so far. 

pls note that this was a tentative to run this outer loop:

for (w = 0 ;w < (numbers.length)/k ;w++) { 
 colonne = [];
  for (j=1;j<k+1;j++ ){
   y = 0*k+j-1;
   colonne[j-1] = numbers[y];
  }
 riga[0] = colonne;
}

Also note that this works:

var numbers = [65, 44, 12, 4, 23 , 42];

function pippo() {
    var k = 3;
    var colonne = [];
    var riga = [[]];

colonne = [65,44,12]

    riga[0] = colonne;
colonne = [4,23,42]

    riga[1] = colonne;

    demo.innerHTML = riga[0].concat(riga[1]);   

}

Answer (score 0):

The below lines are cause `riga[0]` and `riga[1]` to refer the same array `colonne`

```
riga[0] = colonne;
riga[1] = colonne;
```

You should use `Object.assign()` to create a copy of `colonne` Like below

```
riga[0] = Object.assign([],colonne)
```

```js
var numbers = [65, 44, 12, 4, 23, 42];

function pippo() {

  var k = 3;
  var colonne = [];
  var riga = [[]];

  for (j = 1; j < k + 1; j++) {
    y = 0 * k + j - 1;
    colonne[j - 1] = numbers[y];
  }

  riga[0] = Object.assign([], colonne)

  for (j = 1; j < k + 1; j++) {
    y = 1 * k + j - 1;
    colonne[j - 1] = numbers[y];
  }

  riga[1] = colonne

  demo.innerHTML = riga[0].concat(riga[1]);

}
pippo()
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: THX a lot. it may work in the particular case, but it does not work in the more general case where I combine the two loops. To me it 's wierd becasue if instead of loops I assign values to colonne twice... it works.... 

     for (w = 0 ;w < (numbers.length)/k ;w++) { 

 colonne = [];
  
  for (j=1;j<k+1;j++ ){
   y = 0*k+j-1;
   colonne[j-1] = numbers[y];
  }

 riga[0] = Object.assign([],colonne);
 

 
 }

Answer (score 0):

After you do:

```
riga[0] = colonne;
```

... make sure to create a new array:

```
colonne = [];
```

... before you continue with the next loop. Otherwise you will be *modifying* the existing `colonne` array there, which is the same thing as `riga[0]`.

Comment: thx for the quick replay. this work for the particular case, however was trying to run an outer for loop on the two I wrote here: in this this solutions do not works.

Comment: In that case you must do the same after `riga[1] = colonne;`. Same principle. But please update your question with the outer loop so we don't have to guess ;-)

Comment: Also, I understand that  you are saying that arrays works as pointers and not as "memory slots" , but then I do not undersstand why if I assign values to colonne instead of building colonne via the forloops the result is as expected...

Comment: hi trincot I have added a note into the question, with the outerloop code. thx for your help!

Comment: assignment to an array index is not the same as assigning a new array to the variable `colonne` itself. In the first case we say you *mutate* the array -- but it remains the same array object, with some modified content. In the second case, you assign a new array, the old one is no longer referenced by `colonne` (while other variables can continue to reference the old array).

Comment: Hi Trincto, thx. what would be the solution to perform the outeloop I put int the note? thx a lot

Comment: I don't understand how that would work with your innerHTML. Is it inside the outer loop or not? In either case I don't understand the purpose; Can you please click edit under your question and put the code there, so we see the context?